# MVC Reporting - a generic View which will display headers and results irrespective of number of columns in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting

for any new report requirement -

1] We will copy existing page, change sql,  add authorisation and Done. This activity doesn't take more than half an hour.

2] or add IF else block in the existing page.

However in MVC world, I have Controller Action - which will return model to view.

And in View - Result and Headers will be displayed using <% foreach (var item in Model) %>

Here I want a generic View which will display headers and results irrespective of number of columns in Model.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could loop through the headers and values in your view to display them.